# Sleep mode kill my Android process

Tags: android, service, wakelock, kill-process

When my device is in sleep mode, something kills my process. I used a Huaweii or Samsung using a Databackground in Off. What am I need to control this problem?

I put in my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

and in my service

```
 startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
```

Answer (score 1):

There could be two reasons:

It could just be the code from onPause, when is sleep mode, android app calls onPause, take this into consideration. [What happens to Activities/Services when phone goes to sleep/standby mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4267897/what-happens-to-activities-services-when-phone-goes-to-sleep-standby-mode)

Any application gets an importance from the OS, when the memory is full, the OS starts to kill processes begining with the less important ones(background for example, then those in visible mode, then those in service and perceptible mode), probably your app goes from foreground to one of those states and the memory gets full. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.html

Answering to your question: you could look over onPause method considering the lifecycle of an application, or you could verify that you phone does not have a lot of applications running such that the RAM is full.